# How to write the result of a calculation to a file in python?

Tags: python, output

I'm doing some calculations after reading a file, and want to store the result (a single number) to another file. I want to be able to do things with this file later. I'm having problems storing the result into the text file.

I tried this:

```
    c = fdata_arry[:,2]*fdata_arry[:,4] 
    d = np.sum(c)
    print d
    f = open('test','w')
    f.write(d) 
    f.close()
```

which gives me this error for the line `f.write(d)`:

> Non-character array cannot be interpreted as character buffer

I also tried using `np.savetxt('test.dat',d)` but that gives me:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Any idea how can I solve this? Note that `d` is just a single value, which is the sum of a few numbers.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255758/numpy-savetxt-tuple-index-out-of-range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write to a file, python wants strings or bytes, not numbers.  Try:

```
f.write('%s' % d)
```

or

```
f.write('{}'.format(d))
```

On the other hand, if you want to write a numpy array to a file and later read it back in *as a numpy array*, use the pickle module.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting d to a string before writing it.

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(d))
```

Also note the use of the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) context manager, which is good practice to always use when opening files.

Answer (score 1):

`write` expects an encoded byte array.

If you are still coding Python 2, you might use `f.write('{:d}\n'.format(d))`.

In Python 3, you can use the cleaner `print(d, file=f)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Given you are working with Numpy may I suggest you take a look at Pandas. That package has a range of input/output functions/methods associated with its DataFrame (2D array), such as [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). You may easily read and write header information with these function and it will take care of the conversion from number to string and back again.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([d], columns=['Sum']).to_csv(open('test.dat', 'w'))
data_read_again = pd.read_csv('test.dat', index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say exactly if the rest of the code is correct or not but I have noticed that you don't specify the file type in the code:

```
f = open('test','w')
```

If it's a .txt you are going for it should read:

```
f = open('test.txt','w')
```